# Inkscape - Force Bounded Region to be Transparent

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to fill a region with a color. Inside this region, there is another region that is on a separate layer (on the highest layer). I want this region to be transparent and to not show the color of the outer region. How can I force an enclosed area to be transparent?

Here are some images to help explain my problem:

This is the graphic I am trying to create.
[image: The graphic I am trying to create]

This is what happens when I fill the inner region with 'none' and the outer region 'grey'
[image: I would like the green area to be transparent]

I would like this green region to be transparent, and not the color of the outer region.
[image: The graphic I am trying to create]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Select and Transform Objects Tool (F1), hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select both the AE letter shape and the inside part of the A, and do *Path > Difference*, or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

This will punch out the top shape as a hole that will be transparent, through which you can see the objects below.

By the way, you don't need everything on separate layers in Inkscape. All you need to do is stack the objects on top of each other within the same layer. You can see the object stack within the layers if you open the Objects panel. You can move objects up and down within the layer using the four buttons in the Tool Controls Bar along the top.

For example:

[image]